# Can a C++ code i wrote on eclipse IDE, run without problems on VC++ IDE?

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++

I'm a bit new to programming and I just wanted to know if there can be any problems if I send my C++ code I wrote on Eclipse to a friend who works on VC++?

Comment: It depends.  How standard compliant is your code?

Comment: Depends, if you have everything made portable, it should work.

Comment: The word "I" is capitalised, as are letters at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: Do you know how can I check if my code is portable, and standard compliant?

Comment: Well you could just see whether it compiles. But to know whether it's _correct_ will require knowing what you're doing. Read the documentation for the language and library features that you use; that'll be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there can be problems.

Whether the code can simply be copy/pasted to another toolchain entirely depends on how *standard-compliant* and *portable* the code is.

We cannot guess at that from here.

Comment: Thank you! I will look up for those terms and see if there can be something that concerns my code.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no problem as long as you are not using any compiler-specific things, which is unlikely if you are a beginner.

Comment: Thank you! I hope you are correct